# Replace url paramer by using php

Tags: php, regex

I have a url & its structure like

```
https://www.example.com/i/location-name/category/subcategory/item/item-id
```

I want to replace the url parameter(***location-name***) dynamically by **new parameter** using PHP.

Modified url is looks like this

```
https://www.example.com/i/new-parameter/category/subcategory/item/item-id
```

I had successfully done with query parameters by using  http_build_query();

But in this case i had tried with preg_replace(), but its not working

Thanks

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use regex.

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/i/location-name/category/subcategory/item/item-id';
$new_param = 'new-parameter';

print preg_replace('|/location-name/|','/'.$new_param.'/',$url);
```

*I don't recommend search for only location-name (without slash) beacause it will match with for example location-names string.*

**UPDATE**

Based on placement not string you can change that part that way:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/i/location-name/category/subcategory/item/item-id';

$new_param = 'new-parameter';
$new_url = preg_replace('|/i/(.*?)/|','/i/'.$new_param.'/',$url);
print $new_url.'<br/>';

$new_param = 'another-parameter';
$new_url = preg_replace('|/i/(.*?)/|','/i/'.$new_param.'/',$url);
print $new_url.'<br/>';
```

You will get:

```
https://www.example.com/i/new-parameter/category/subcategory/item/item-id
https://www.example.com/i/another-parameter/category/subcategory/item/item-id
```

**Alternative solution**
If you would like to be sure about change, you can do it another way, something like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/i/location-name/category/subcategory/item/item-id';
$new_param = 'new-param';
$parts = parse_url($url);
$path_parts = explode('/',$parts['path']);
$path_parts[2] = $new_param;

$new_path = implode('/',$path_parts);

$new_url = $parts['scheme'].'://'.$parts['host'].$new_path;

print( $new_url);
```

Comment: 'location-name' is generated dynamically. First time it is 'abc', then the next time it is 'xxx' etc. So how can i replace it.

Comment: any idea to replace 'i/xxxxxxxx/' to 'i/newone/'

Comment: I supposed you will need replace based on placement not on string, I will provide you an another solution for that. One sec :)

Comment: `$new_url = preg_replace('|/i/(.*?)/|','/'.$new_param.'/',$url);`

Comment: Thank you very much Csimpi :). Its working as expected

Comment: You're welcome, check the alternative (more secure) solution below. Have a good day! :)

Comment: Take care that actually your pattern matches also `/i` that is missing in your replacement string. Add it, or you can also change the pattern like this: `$new_url = preg_replace('~/i/\K[^/]*~', $new_param, $url, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$new_url = str_replace('location-name', 'my-location', 'https://www.example.com/i/location-name/category/subcategory/item/item-id')
```